# PLSQL - Count of all characters within a string

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql, character

I want to be able to generate a count of all characters in a given string from the result of an Oracle PLSQL query.

For instance, given the string "strings", output would be as such

```
character | count
-----------------
g         | 1
i         | 1
n         | 1
r         | 1
s         | 2
t         | 1
```

My thinking was something along the lines of

```
SELECT COLUMN, COUNT(COLUMN) FROM TABLE GROUP BY COLUMN
```

but that would require converting a string into a set of characters which is where I'm stuck.

Ideally this extends to a count of all ASCII characters not just A-Z, in order to perform analysis on the contents of the database.

I'm curious if there's a better way to do this than creating a procedure and whitelisting characters to count and running that on a given string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a commonly used way to split a string into characters;
once you have one record for each character, counting them is quite straightforward:

```
select single_char, count(*)
from (
    select substr(x, level, 1) as single_char
    from (select 'abbabbaccb' x from dual)
    connect by level <= length(x)
    )
group by single_char
```